# Bookmarklets on IOS 8

Tags: iphone, safari, ios

I can't find anything about this on Google, but it appears Safari on IOS8 no longer supports `javascript:` bookmarklets.

Can anyone confirm this?

Is there a workaround?

I'm using iPhone 6 plus if for some reason this matters.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm this. Have just tried with a bookmarklet from Instapaper and it had no problem posting a link to the page viewed. Is there a particular bookmarklet that causes you grief?

Comment: Everywhere I try to use a bookmark that uses the JavaScript protocol.  Safari throws an alert that says something like "JavaScript cannot be called in this way".